# Structured lighting basic principles for depth mapping

Tags: computer-vision

I've been wondering, how, in the most simple-to-implement basic principle, does the light projection to depth map technique described here https://www.lightform.com/how-it-works actually functions? Is it some kind of an average based on the color of x pixel over all the patterns or what? How difficult would it be to code something that could do this, up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*how, in the most simple-to-implement basic principle, does the light projection to depth map technique described here https://www.lightform.com/how-it-works actually functions?Is it some kind of an average based on the color of x pixel over all the patterns or what?*

No it is not that simple , more details on that are described in *https://kevinkarsch.com/publications/sa11-lowres.pdf*

P.S the author of this paper went on to become CTO of lightform.

*Is it some kind of an average based on the color of x pixel over all the patterns or what? How difficult would it be to code something that could do this, up?*

As mentioned above it is not simple average based on color , coding would be a tough task , you could implement model if you are capable enough to code a ray-tracer from scratch. But replicating the exact results would require a lot of low-level knowledge and certain domain expertise as not much of the implementation details and hyperparameters are described.

Comment: Cool, although this seems to do 3d based on color image input, What about the structured lighting approach Lightform uses?